# Ionic cordova splash screen

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Ionic and Cordova.

I have already changed the config.xml to:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

and have removed splashscreen plugin

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Can't remove the splash screen.

Comment: How have you changed the code in your application to remove the splash screen? Just posting an image of the splash screen is of no help *at all*.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for so little info.

Comment: Also note that iOS and Android have very specific features for iOS/Android (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/core/features/splashscreen/index.html). What platform(s) are you looking at? What are you trying to do?

Comment: From Android 12 impossible to remove
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67921860/disable-android-12-default-splash-screen/68016634#68016634
But you can change behavior
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110639/remove-default-splash-screen-from-android-12-example

Answer (score 4):

You can add white (or another) splashscreen.

- `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen`
- Create folder `res/screen/android/`
- Create folder `res/screen/ios/`
- Create file `res/screen/android/splashscreen.xml` with vector image. Here is example of white vector image:

```
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="512dp"
    android:height="512dp"
    android:viewportWidth="512"
    android:viewportHeight="512">
    <group
        android:pivotX="243"
        android:pivotY="256"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5">
            <path
                android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:fillType="evenOdd"
                android:pathData="M425.22,448h-62.16l4.34,-54.86h-30.54L332.52,448H203.68l-4.34,-54.86H168.8l4.34,54.86h-62.16L76.1,210.22L163.38,64h209.44l87.28,146.22L425.22,448zM355.29,137.21h-56.02l3.79,27.43h-69.93l3.79,-27.43h-56.02l-35.06,73.02l17.53,146.22h209.44l17.53,-146.22L355.29,137.21zM324.75,308.02c-4.88,0 -8.67,-15.13 -8.67,-34.05s3.98,-34.05 8.67,-34.05c4.88,0 8.67,15.13 8.67,34.05S329.63,308.02 324.75,308.02zM214.7,310.86c-4.88,0 -8.67,-15.13 -8.67,-34.05s3.98,-34.05 8.67,-34.05c4.88,0 8.67,15.13 8.67,34.05S219.4,310.86 214.7,310.86z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

- Add this code inside section `<platform name="android">`. Code:

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/splashscreen.xml" />
```

Comment: can you explain the full path of these folders res/screen ?

Comment: @exequielc it is from root path of your project. For example "c:\projects_cordova\yourproject\res\screen\android\splashscreen.xml"