# How to implement the new cordova android 11 splash screen in android and ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, splash-screen

In the past, I was providing an icon.png and splash.png and by running
`ionic cordova resources`

i was generating the resources i needed to use in my config.xml like this:

[image]
With the new way of generating my splash screen, at least for Android, im only adding this to my config.xml:

`<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screen/android/splashscreen.xml"/>`

My question is, do I still need to run ionic cordova resources because of iOS?
Because if I do, it will generate <splash> tags for android too and it comes up with a warning saying im already using AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon and i should not have <splash> tags

I would be able to do ionic cordova resources --icon to only generate icons, but that wouldnt generate splash screen for iOS, i guess..

Thank you in advance for your help. Im a bit confused

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic cordova splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018675/ionic-cordova-splash-screen)

Answer (score -1):

Cordova resources accepts the platform name as a parameter. You can run:

```
ionic cordova resources ios --splash
```